# Is IMsRdpDeviceV2 documented in MSDN but not available in mstscax.dll?

Tags: windows, com, activex

I am using mstsc RDP API for remote connection.I have seen in MSDN there is an api for device redirection from mstsc activex.

As per MSDN **IMsRdpDeviceV2** is an enhancement of the **IMsRdpDevice** interface.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/termserv/imsrdpdevicev2

```
Checked dll version
 - 10.0.17134
 - 10.0.16299
 - 10.0.15063
 - 10.0.14393
 - 10.0.10290
 - 6.1.7601
```

Where can i find **IMsRdpDeviceV2**?

Comment: Have you noticed IMsRdpDeviceV2's guid is declared in that file here https://github.com/awakecoding/TsTeleport/blob/master/DVCSample/include/mstsax.h (I have no idea where that file comes from but it has what seems to be an official Microsoft header) for another interface `IMsRdpDeviceCEV2. Note the "CE" (Compact Edition) suffix, and the interface declaration is different. It's not in a Windows 10 mstscax.dll either. Something is wrong indeed... I guess you can forget about using this phantom interface.

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier,  it is not present from long back
 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7ccd1148-bb37-4d6f-94bd-9f310c62c089/remote-desktop-dynamic-usb-device-redirection